# Определить тактовую частоту процессора c#

Tags: c#, железо, процесс

Одно за заданий в курсовой требует получить тактовую частоту процессора в данный момент времени. Честно говоря перекопал все что можно (system.diagnostics, system.management) и все это не слишком помогло. Все что я смог вытащить, так это максимальная тактовая частота процессора (можно было не мучиться и вытащить ее из реестра), но к сожалению необходима частота в определенный момент времени.
Может кто нибудь подсказать как это сделать и возможно ли это вообще (как я понял мне нужны данные показанные в диспетчере задач как скорость процессора в ггц).
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит покопать в сторону WinAPI + P/Invoke.

Comment: Вот [это обсуждение на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8353086/276994) говорит, что «дешёвого» надёжного пути определить _текущую_ частоту нету, можно лишь использовать особенности каждого из процессоров, поддерживая базу данных существующих процессоров.

Если вам нужна не текущая частота, registry is your friend.

Кстати, если это курсовая, спросите у автора задания. Если он старше 40 лет, возможно, он не знает сам, что это невозможно, и хочет от вас грубый хак, не работающий на многозадачных ОС и современных процессорах (например, гонять пустой цикл и измерять его время).

Comment: Что значит:

    частота в определенный момент времени

Тактовая частота ЦП - величина постоянная! Или, может, вы имеете ввиду загрузку ЦП в определенный момент времени?

Comment: @0xFFh: уже нет. Некоторые процессоры сбрасывают частоту в idle-режиме для экономии электроэнергии.

Comment: Или повышают её под нагрузкой, или понижают при перегреве (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Троттлинг).

Answer (score 3):

Параметры процессора в Windows можно получить с помощью WMI
[Win32_Processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx). Например, CurrentClockSpeed можно получить так:

```
using System.Management;
using System.Linq;
var s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_processor");
var o = s.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First();
o["CurrentClockSpeed"]
```